# Condition on composition functions for the given fact to be true in case of codomain off is not same the domain of g

Tags: functions, function-and-relation-composition

We know that for $f:Y \to Z$ and $g:X \to Y$ , if $f \circ g$ is either bijective or just surjective or injective we have $g$ is injective and $f$ is surjective for first case, similarily $f$ is surjective only for second case and $g$ is injective for third case. But what happens when we have functions of form $f:X \to Y$ and $g:Z \to W$ here can we say the same conclusions for $f \circ g$ when its either of the above three cases?

Comment: Be careful: function composition is *from right to left*. As written, you can't construct $f \circ g$.

Comment: Oh, you just edited to fix this. :-)

Comment: Yeah just edited thanks for telling

Comment: The composition in the final question still doesn't make sense though. The codomain of $g$ must be the domain of $f$ in order to define the composition $f \circ g$.

Comment: Yeah i mean as fog is given to be one if the three cases we can assume fog composition is well defined that is the codomain of g in domain of f :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the latter case is not valid. The composition of functions is defined by: $$f \circ g, g: X \rightarrow Y, f:Y \rightarrow Z$$ where X, Y, and Z are sets. $\forall$ x  $\in$ X, f(x) is in the domain of g. I think that the only case that it would be valid is if Y = Z.

Comment: I needed condition on X,Y,Z,W in my case . Can you explain in brief?

Comment: We have the condition for fog to be defined that $g[Z]$ $\cap$ $X$ is some non zero set